# Monthly aggregate calculations and looping through string values

Tags: string, loops, ms-access

I would like to modify the following query so that it will sum monthly sales for each salesperson, not just one salesperson.  I believe it requires a VB loop that can loop through string values but I don't know VB so if you could provide detailed information I would appreciate it.

```sql
SELECT Format(DatePart("m",months.month_start),"00") & "/" & Year(months.month_start) AS [Month/Year],

(Select sales_rep.rep_name  FROM SALES_REP
WHERE SALES_REP.rep_Name = "Eileen") AS [Sales Person],

(select Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2) 
FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN SALES_REP ON SALES_REP.REP_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.REP_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end and  SALES_REP.rep_Name = "Eileen") AS [Total Sales], 

(SELECT Round((Sum(((Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.SELLING_PRICE,0)*Nz(sales_receipt.quantity,0))*(Nz(sales_receipt.commission_percent,100)*0.001)))),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN SALES_REP ON SALES_REP.REP_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.REP_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end and SALES_REP.rep_Name = "Eileen") AS [Gross Commission] 

FROM
(SELECT DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), 1) AS month_start, DateAdd("d", -1,
DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date) + 1, 1)) AS month_end FROM SALES_RECEIPT WHERE sale_date between #1/1/2015# And #12/31/2050# 
GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date)) AS months;
```

Comment: Your answer to my posting above worked great!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @HansUp. Please post comment as answer, so OP can accept and resolve.

Comment: Also to the OP, your last 6 questions have been nearly the same. While we welcome your participation, please try to learn SQL, subqueries and aggregation. Many online tutorials are available. Let's keep SO rich with rigor and diversity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple `GROUP BY` query, instead of one with all those subqueries, should make it easier to work out the logic and would probably offer better runtime performance as well.  I don't see any reason why you should need VBA for this.

```sql
SELECT
    Format(SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE, 'yyyy-mm') AS [Year-Month],
    SALES_REP.rep_Name,
    Sum(SALES_RECEIPT.SELLING_PRICE * SALES_RECEIPT.quantity),
    Sum((Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.SELLING_PRICE,0) * Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.quantity,0))
        * (Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.commission_percent, 100) * 0.001))
FROM
    SALES_RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN SALES_REP
    ON SALES_REP.REP_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.REP_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE BETWEEN #2015-1-1# AND #2050-12-31#
GROUP BY
    Format(SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE, 'yyyy-mm'),
    SALES_REP.rep_Name;
```